# NSDateFormatter not getting date string parsed

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

This is probably obvious, but I can't seem to convert a date string into an NSDate object. Trying with:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[df setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *server = [df dateFromString:result];
```

where result is a c# datetime object converted to a string coming from a webservice.  It looks like "12/14/2012 8:00:27 PM".  'server' just keeps coming up as nil.

Also, after i get it to an NSDate, i need to find the difference between 'server' and current time, in hours-minutes-seconds.  Should I use NSDateComponents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[df setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
```

later

> where `result` [...] looks like `"12/14/2012 8:00:27 PM"`

It certainly doesn't have the format you set, so what do you expect? You have to set the [correct format](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html) in order to get this working.

Comment: yep I'm dumb.  I was thinking about this like DateTime.ToString().  Thanks.